# Calling same function on many worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I have an Excel file that is a calendar with some specifications. I have code that will send emails, according to what is selected on the calendar.
When I click the command button on the sheet that corresponds to January, the emails are prepared.

I don't think it makes sense to repeat the code on the other sheets, but I don't know how to call it from there.

This is part of the code I have on the January sheet.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call sendEmail_testemunho("Semana1")
End Sub


Public Sub sendEmail_testemunho(nSemana As String)

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    
    Dim testemunho, hcell, cell, mcell, rgHorarios, diasSemana As Range
    Set testemunho = Range(nSemana)
    Set diasSemana = Range("DiasSemana")
    
    Set emails = Worksheets("Publicadores Locais Horários").ListObjects("emails").Range
   ...
   ...
   ...

Set testemunho = Nothing


ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Message & " on line " & Erl    
End Sub
```

I tried to call the sub on another sheet. It sends this error.

> Compile error:
> Sub or Function not defined

[image: error1]

I also tried to copy and paste the first sheet. When I click the button I have another error.

> Runtime error '438':
> Object doesn't support this property or method

[image: error2]

Comment: Why make it private?

Comment: @findwindow I just started working with VBA. I put the Sub sendEmail_testemunho public because I thought it would solve my problem. If I put the sub CommandButton1_Click public, how would I call it from another sheet?

Comment: Oh so you are calling sendemail from a different button on the other sheet? That should work I think...

Comment: @findwindow  I tried to do that, but when I click the button I got the first error.

Comment: `Dim testemunho, hcell, cell, mcell, rgHorarios, diasSemana As Range`..... FYI this line is probably not behaving the way you expect. `diasSemana` is `Range` and the rest of the variables are not explicitly defined and thus have defaulted to `Variant`

Comment: @ urdearboy I didn't know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the codename as prefix

Code in January-sheet: codename = wsJanuary

```vb
Public sub sendMail(Email as string)
  msgbox email
End sub
```

Code in Febuary-sheet: codename = wsFebuary

```vb
Public sub sendMail(Email as string)
  wsJanuary.sendMail Email
End sub
```

**BUT the better solution would be to put `sendMail` into a normal module. Then you can access it without prefix.**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realise I hadn't change the name of the sheet. So when I tried january.senEmail it didn't work. But, how can I do that better solution you said?

Comment: Add a regular module (if you don't have yet) and put there the Sub `sendEmail_testemunho`. You can call it then just by the subs name without prefix